# How to keep a session for Localization & Globalization?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, forms

i would like to know how to keep a session or how to make the browser remember which language should the application keep while navigating and moving from a page to another should i recall the overrided methode :

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()  
        {  
            base.InitializeCulture();  
            string cult = Request["lstLanguage"];  
            if (cult != null)  
            {  
                Culture = cult;  
                UICulture = cult;  
            }  
}
```

i've tried :

```
Session["cult"] = cult;
```

but it does not work
more informations there is a a drop down list at the home page which make the user choose the language.
what should i do ? thanks

Comment: Please define 'does not work'

Comment: i did not know how to use it properly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the selected culture in a cookie. That way, when the user returns to your site the culture will be "remembered".

Using Session will mean the user has to keep choosing the culture when they return - not good.

You can access the site's cookies with the Request object:

```
Request.Cookies["culture"].Value = chosenCultureCode;
```

Comment: thanks Joe R ! would you mind sending me any tutorial ? or an exemple ?

Comment: Ok, no problem. I've added a code snippet for setting a culture cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the users specified Culture in the session when the user first logs into the system. Then you can use it in your InitializeCulture methods.

eg. when login

Session["CurrentCulture"] = (Your users chosen culture)

and in your override for InitializeCulture you would retrieve with:

Session["CurrentCulture"].

Here is an example of one of my methods.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes culture for the page
    /// </summary>
    [VersionChange( "6.1.34.89", "24/12/2009", "Custom Cultures added" )]
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        try
        {
            CultureInfo oCultureInfo;

            try
            {
                oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
            }
            catch ( ArgumentException )
            {
                //Get culture info based on Great Britain
                CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "en-GB" );
                RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo( cultureInfo.Name );

                CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( this.CurrentCustomCulture, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None );

                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo( cultureInfo );
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo( regionInfo );

                // Custom Changes
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;

                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();

                oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oCultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = oCultureInfo;

            Page.Culture = oCultureInfo.Name;
            Page.UICulture = oCultureInfo.Name;

            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This.CurrentCustomCulture is my session property

Comment: The problem with using Session is the user has to keep choosing their culture when they return to the site. Depending on your requirements, this may not be user-friendly.

Comment: when i keep the cookie should recall the InitializeCulture Method and asign the cookie's value ?

Comment: @Joe R, Yes, I would expect the data to be persisted to a database or such and it to be loaded and the session populated when the user logs in. Depends on whehter this is a private or public facing application

Comment: One thing to also note about storing stuff in cookies is that if the user happens to have In Privatte Browsing turned on, none of your cookies will work

Comment: @Houssam - good man. @WraithNath - good point. Fortunately, that scenario is rare.